# Fixed element getting clipped by overflow in Safari

Tags: css, ios, layout, safari, webkit

It's probably a webkit bug (discussed [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=160953)) and I'm trying to find a workaround for that.

The problem is that fixed div cuts by it's parent (which is smaller) at least in Safari on iOS 12.3.1

[Example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/coxoye/2/edit?html,output)

```css
.container {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: scroll;
    
  
      /* This should create a new stacking context, but not a containing block. 
        Safari does create a containing block for these instead :/
      */
      opacity: 0.99;
      /* same for these other properties: 
      position: fixed;
      mix-blend-mode: multiply;
      filter: blur(0px); */
    }
    
    .fixed {
      position: fixed;
      padding: 20px;
      top: 40px;
      left: 40px;
      width: 150px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed">
      I should not get clipped!
    </div>
</div>
```